# Alfresco transformation priority

Tags: alfresco, transformation

I would like to use a new transformer in Alfresco to transform a docx to a pdf and then use this transformation to create the flash preview.

Is there a way to force alfresco to use this transformer if the standard transformer is faster?

I want to use the new transformer because the rendered document is better.

I know that there is a method called getTransformationTime in AbstractContentTransformer2 that returns the average transformation time. 
As a workaround I return always 0. I do not like this solution and it is not always enough: sometimes alfresco uses the standard transformation because the first time its average time is considered 0.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Transformers are configured using Spring beans. Why not override the default transformer.OOXML bean and point to your class instead? That bean lives in $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/content-services-context.xml in 4.2.f. There may be additional beans you may need to override to achieve exactly what you are trying to, but this should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I think that I cannot override the default transformer because my transformer is available only for docx. I need also the option to disable the custom transformer with a flag in alfresco-global.properties.